# Return 2 values from a PL-SQL function

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can i return 2 values from a PL-SQL function?

Comment: you can't return two value... one thing you can do is.. make an array n merge both values.and return it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can return one value directly and another one as an OUT parameter. Or you return a record that contains both values. The first option is, in most cases, simpler to do.

Comment: It is generally regarded as bad practice to have an OUT parameter in a function's signature.

Comment: Function should return 1 value, a stored procedure can and should be used to return more than one value.

Answer (score 13):

I would not advocate creating a function with an OUT parameter for the second value, because I like to think of functions as a pure concept: a function performs an operation on one or more inputs to produce **one** output.  It shouldn't change any of its arguments or have any other "side effects".

So if you need two outputs, write a **procedure** instead:

```
procedure get_sqrt_and_half
   ( p_input number
   , p_sqrt OUT number
   , p_half OUT number
   )
is
begin
   p_sqrt := sqrt(p_input);
   p_half := p_input/2;
end;
```

Comment: I concur with Tony. Anything that has more than one output, or use IN OUT parameters should be a procedure. By keeping functions clean (no external side effects) it becomes a lot easier to chain function calls together, which you cannot easily do when there are in/out parameters.

Remember that the output of a function can be a complex type - %ROWTYPE, user-defined record, object type, collection, or ref cursor - there are lots of ways to return complex data.

Answer (score 6):

A function can only return a single SQL type, but that can be a user-defined type with multiple values. I'd need to know more about the actual end requirements before I'd recommend this as a solution, but it is a possibility.

```
create or replace type a_b is object (a number, b number);
/

create or replace function ret_a_b return a_b is
begin
  return a_b(1,2);
end;
/

select ret_a_b from dual;

select d.rab.a, d.rab.b from (select ret_a_b rab from dual) d;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
**If you are wanting to use it in SQL, then you would need a pipelined function e.g.**

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE myemp AS OBJECT
 ( empno    number,
   ename    varchar2(10),
   job      varchar2(10),
   mgr      number,
   hiredate date,
   sal      number,
   comm     number,
   deptno   number
 );

 CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE myrectable AS TABLE OF myemp ;


    enter code here

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pipedata(p_min_row number, p_max_row number) RETURN myrectable PIPELINED IS
    v_obj myemp := myemp(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
 BEGIN
   FOR e IN (select *
             from (
                   select e.*
                         ,rownum rn
                   from (select * from emp order by empno) e
                  )
             where rn between p_min_row and p_max_row)
   LOOP
     v_obj.empno    := e.empno;
     v_obj.ename    := e.ename;
     v_obj.job      := e.job;
     v_obj.mgr      := e.mgr;
     v_obj.hiredate := e.hiredate;
     v_obj.sal      := e.sal;
     v_obj.comm     := e.comm;
     v_obj.deptno   := e.deptno;
     PIPE ROW (v_obj);
   END LOOP;
   RETURN;
 END;

SQL> select * from table(pipedata(1,5));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `OUT` parameters:

```
create or replace function f(a IN NUMBER, b OUT NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
  b := a;
  RETURN a;
END f;
```